# Setting up the fist day of the week. Calendar. JS

Tags: javascript, calendar, weekday

I used [this script](http://jszen.blogspot.ru/2007/03/how-to-build-simple-calendar-with.html) to create a calendar with JavaScript. I rewrote it enough, for instance, I built viewing of the previous and next month's days, viewing previous or next month, etc. But the basic algorithm  remains the same as it was written in that article (for loops "// fill in the days").

Well now, when everything works pretty good, I need the first day of the week to be Monday, not Sunday. Unfortunately, I can't imagine how to change the loops in order this feature to work.

So, how do I need to change the loops to make Monday the first day of the week? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code for week starting from Monday: http://jsfiddle.net/VL44m/

Two changes were made:

From `cal_days_labels = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];`
To `cal_days_labels = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat','Sun'];`

From

```
// this loop is for weekdays (cells)
    for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
```

To

```
// this loop is for weekdays (cells)
    for (var j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me a lot. Unfortunately, I can't vote up your post because of the lack of reputation.

Comment: This code doesn't work for month starting on Sunday (eg. nov 2015).

Comment: True. You should consider Jack NUMBER answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here an enhancement of the Nikhil Talreja's code:
http://codepen.io/jacknumber/pen/RWLyQW

To fix month started by Sunday and avoid list of month length, use this:

```
var startingDay = firstDay.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : firstDay.getDay();
```