# How to change calendar's start date layout from Sunday to Monday?

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

Hi I'm trying to learn JavaScript from this calendar example code by the author xMark.  But his example uses Sunday as the first day of the week.  I want it to show Monday as the first day of the week.  So far I have only managed to change the header labels but not the dates' correct positions.
https://codepen.io/xmark/pen/WQaXdv

So I've been trying to understand where in his code I can make the dates shift one step to the left.  But I can't figure out where in the code this shift should occur.

The section where I'm mostly stuck is in `Calendar.prototype.showMonth = function(y, m) {...}` where I think is the part that requires changing.  In this function I don't understand why the author `var k = lastDay_of_LastMonth - firstDay_of_Month+1;` adds +1 to the last variable?

After `var k = ...` I'm completely lost.  Whenever I try to change things the whole calendar just breaks apart.

@Naguib

```js
var d7 = new Date(2018, 6, 1);
d7
"Sun Jul 01 2018" 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
 
var firstDay_of_Month = new Date(2018, 6, 1).getDay();
firstDay_of_Month
0 // July 1st is on a Sunday.
 
//_________________________________________________________________
 
var d8 = new Date(2018, 7, 1);
d8
"Wed Aug 01 2018" 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
 
var firstDay_of_Month = new Date(2018, 7, 1).getDay();
firstDay_of_Month
3 // August 1st is on a Wednesday.
 
//_________________________________________________________________
 
var dNaguib = new Date(2018, 6, 7);
dNaguib
"Sat Jul 07 2018" 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
 
var dNaguib = new Date(2018, 6, 7).getDay();
dNaguib
6 // July 7th is on a Saturday.
 
 
// Why then does this dynamic code looking for the 7th each month
// make everything in the calendar work?
var firstDay_of_Month = new Date(y, m, 7).getDay(); // Naguib


// While the original code looking for the 1st each month make
// some months break the calendar?
var firstDay_of_Month = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay(); // Original
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the codepen you attached and went through every part in the code where Sunday is mentioned and modified it to become this: https://codepen.io/naguibihab/pen/aKMYpB

Here are the changes that I did: https://github.com/naguibihab/js-goodies/commit/aa14d87eea68860650aee3383b458a0b00fb64a9

I'll explain why I did each change, this is taking me back to my college days where I have to explain my code so bear with me:

1:

```
  this.DaysOfWeek = [
    'Mon',
    'Tue',
    'Wed',
    'Thu',
    'Fri',
    'Sat',
    'Sun'
  ];
```

That's the header row's title in the calendar, that's simply text no logic changes there

2: `firstDayOfMonth = 6`
Your first day of the month is now Monday and not Sunday, you can also write `, firstDayOfMonth = new Date(y, m, 7).getDay()` to get the same result but I think the first one makes it a bit clearer to the reader as we'll always be getting `6` anyway

3: `if ( dow == 1 ) {` start a new row on Monday instead of Sunday

4: `if ( dow == 0 ) {` close the row on Sunday instead of Saturday

5: `for(dow; dow < 7; dow++) {` next month's "not-current" numbers can go up to Sunday so we need an extra iteration there (There might be a better way to do that without increasing iterations but I'm too lazy to figure it out now)

It mostly is a concept of "try to change something and see what happens" kind of method to get there, so what I did was go over each area where I suspect Sunday is affecting the code and tried to change it to see what happens.

Let me know in the comments if that doesn't make enough sense.

Comment: Thanks Naguib my entire calendar seems to be bug free now because of this code that you suggested. `var firstDay_of_Month = new Date(y, m, 7).getDay();` But I don't understand why it works since the static version of it only worked on July but was buggy on other months where 1st wasn't on a Sunday `firstDayOfMonth = 6`.

.

I did a test.  `var dNaguib = new Date(2018, 6, 7);` dNaguib `"Sat Jul 07 2018"`. dNaguib.getDay(); displays 6.  July 7th is on a Saturday.  I don't understand the relation between this test and your dynamic line of code?

Comment: Because that code is what determines what day the 1st should be located in each month, but looking at the date 7th of each month seems weird.

Comment: First of all thanks for naming a variable after me. the getDay() function returns you a number from 0-6 based on the day of the week, 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday. So even though Saturday falls on the 7th of July, the function is saying hey this is a Saturday, it'll give you the same result if you ran `Date(2018, 6, 14)`

Comment: I updated the code section at the very top to show you my isolated tests in its entirety.  So what I don't understand is why `var firstDay_of_Month = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay(); // Original` breaks the calendar for certain months.  While this code makes each month display correctly `var firstDay_of_Month = new Date(y, m, 7).getDay(); // Naguib`.  The Original code looks for the 1st date each month while your's looks for the 7th date each month should this difference matter?

Comment: Because for July looking at dates 7th, 14th, 28th you always get Saturday.  But looking for the same dates 7th, 14th, 28th  for August gives you Tuesdays.  This is what makes me confused when looking at that code.  I see that it makes everything in the calendar work but I don't understand why?

Comment: @Abby note that when you run new Date() it gets the day you're on right now, so running this code yesterday might be different from running it today. The original getDate(y,m,1) would get the first day of the month (0-6 sun-sat) what we want though will **always** be saturday, so there's no point in doing that, rather we should just go and do `firstDay_of_Month = 6` instead of relying on a changing variable such as Date(). Does that make sense?

Comment: This is heavy doc!  I think I need to let it boil for some weeks before the coin drops :)  Could you recap again why we want the first day of the month to always be Saturday?  Because when I look at my PC's Windows calendar the dates 1st Jan, 1st Feb, 1st March, ..., 1st Dec falls on different days of the week.  So when you say this variable needs to have a static value and when I see that this static way makes everything work for each month then I get confused.

Comment: @Abby isn't that what you're trying to do? Have the view in the calendar start on a Saturday rather than a Sunday?

Comment: Ah sorry, I rechecked the code, I mean Monday not Saturday, when `firstDay_of_Month = 6` that means we're starting the view with a Monday

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/VL44m/) from Nikhil Talreja. It should give you a good idea as to how to get the calendar working with Monday as a start date. A[lso, check out the similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624303/setting-up-the-fist-day-of-the-week-calendar-js)

Essentially, he uses some for loops and labels, such that:

```
cal_days_labels = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat','Sun'];
```

and

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
```

The project is similar to yours I would imagine, so hopefully this helps.